# What do they mean “ US Internal Revenue Service that gave it back 810 millions?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

here is the context

> In the quarter ended in March, IBM’s revenues rose by 5.1 percent to $19.1 billion, and its gross profits were up by 6.1 percent to $8.25 billion. There were a whole bunch of things that affected the **bottom line** in the quarter, including a settlement of two audits by the **US Internal Revenue Service that gave it back $810 million**, but IBM then took $610 million in restructuring charges for unspecified layoffs. The company also took some charges – IBM’s chief financial officer, Jim Cavanaugh, did not say how much – that pushed its overall systems business into the red ink.

Why did US IRS gave 810 to IBM? and what do they mean by saying bottom line?

Comment: This is a financial rather than a linguistic question. My understanding is that the US IRS (the US tax agency) performed two audits, and that as a result of the settlement of those audits IBM recovered $810 million. It's not the IRS but the settlement of the two audits that gave IBM back that amount.

Comment: You should have no trouble finding a definition for "bottom line".  Post if you find something that doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: do they mean the final balance sheet here ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finance, with only a tiny element of it about the meaning of terms (which could easily be looked up).

Answer (score 1):

The *subject* of this paragraph is the company *IBM*. So the "it" in the section you enquire about refers to that company.

> "...**two audits** by the US Internal Revenue Service that **gave it back $810 million**..."

So the two audits resulted in a refund of $810 million to IBM. Effectively it was the *audits* that "gave" back that money.

The "bottom line" in accounting is the final figure you reach after your calculations. In simple terms, the amount of money received is set against all outgoings that are allowable for taxation purposes and the difference is taxable. An audit is a process that *checks* those calculations for mistakes. So I get from this that the initial calculations by the Revenue service were incorrect leading to an inflated "bottom line" and caused IBM pay $810 million more tax than they needed to. The audits corrected this and the money was returned.

Comment: I agree, but why an audit should return money to IBM?

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby added detail to answer.

Comment: thank you, but how an audit can be wrong for 810million dollars ? Sounds a little strange to me

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby I agree it sounds a lot of money, but IBM is a big company. Also, a quick Google of this matter shows that this $810m was from US *and foreign* tax audits, so perhaps your source is slightly incorrect and this didn't all come back from the US Revenue service?

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby Also... another quick Google shows that this refund was for "non-cash, tax benefits". I'm not an expert but I believe this refers to taxation of things that are *not* cash... so it may sound a lot compared to IBM's quarterly turnover but it may be that the incorrect taxation was applied to things like company assets, vehicles... non-cash things that should have been tax exempt.

Comment: I posted this into economic group, I am curious about some specific examples in order to understand what they really mean?

Comment: here in my country has something like VAT that the country is turning back if you have more than a specific amoont of money generated. For example - you bought a new car for your business and at the end of the fiscal year, they will return 20% of the money as stated in the law but only if some specific conditions of the company abides the laws. So I wonder if this is the case scenario here

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby This isn't really about the English anymore and is more of a financial question. Final word on the answer - VAT is a tax added *at point of sale* both at wholesale and then at resale. The only thing allowed against collected VAT is *paid* VAT, and the balance is paid to Revenue. No other allowances are made. For that reason I don't believe this article is talking about VAT, but Business Tax (or whatever it is called in the country of origin).

Comment: Actually it was not "two audits" that gave back money, it was "a settlement".

Comment: @Hellion That doesn't really affect the question or my answer. Lots of English literature has an "unreliable narrator". We can comment on the grammar whether the quotation is reliable or not.

Comment: I don't understand where an 'unreliable narrator' comes into play for a financial quote from a news agency?  Anyway, my point is that if you're trying to guide the OP to the subject of "gave", you pointed to part of the other prepositional phrase instead of the actual subject, so they're not going to be able to figure out future cases based on this.